# slider i want move 4 images every button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for slider button, i want move 4 images every button click. and make the button not active when all images slides if right or left. (sorry if my English not good)

```
$(document).on('click', '.px-carousel-nav .px-next', function() {
        var sumando_ancho = width_total();
        // Si el ancho generado es menor al ancho del contenedor, no hacer nada
        if (sumando_ancho < $('.px-carousel-wrapper').width()) {
            return false;
        }
        $('.px-carousel-container').css({
            'min-width': ''
        }); // reset
        var position_items = posiciones();

        var rev = -1;
        if (is_rtl()) {
            rev = 1;
        }
        var translate = getTranslate3d(document.getElementsByClassName('px-carousel-container')[0]) * rev;

        var now_ = 0;
        $.each(position_items, function(index, value) {
            if (value.toFixed(2) > translate) {
                now_ = value * rev;

                return false;
            }
        });
        var diferencia = ($('.px-carousel-wrapper').outerWidth() - sumando_ancho);

        $('.px-carousel-container').animate({
            example: now_,
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                switch (fx.prop) {
                    case 'example':
                        $(this).css({
                            'transform': 'translate3d(' + now + 'px, 0px, 0px)',
                            'transition': 'all 0.25s ease 0s'
                        });
                        if (is_rtl()) {
                            if (now >= diferencia * -1) {

                                $('.px-carousel-container').stop();
                                $(this).css({
                                    'transform': 'translate3d(' + ((diferencia * -1)) + 'px, 0px, 0px)',
                                    'transition': 'all 0.25s ease 0s'
                                });
                                break;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (now <= diferencia) {

                                $('.px-carousel-container').stop();
                                $(this).css({
                                    'transform': 'translate3d(' + (diferencia) + 'px, 0px, 0px)',
                                    'transition': 'all 0.25s ease 0s'
                                });
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                }
            },
            duration: 100,
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.px-carousel-nav .px-prev', function() {
        $('.px-carousel-container').css({
            'min-width': ''
        }); // reset
        var sumando_ancho = width_total();
        var position_items = posiciones().reverse();

        var rev = -1;
        if (is_rtl()) {
            rev = 1;
        }
        var translate = getTranslate3d(document.getElementsByClassName('px-carousel-container')[0]) * rev;

        var now_ = 0;
        $.each(position_items, function(index, value) {
            if (value.toFixed(2) < translate) {
                now_ = value * rev;

                return false;
            }
        });

        var diferencia = ($('.px-carousel-wrapper').outerWidth() - sumando_ancho);

        $('.px-carousel-container').animate({
            example: now_,
        }, {
            step: function(now, fx) {
                switch (fx.prop) {
                    case 'example':
                        $(this).css({
                            'transform': 'translate3d(' + now + 'px, 0px, 0px)',
                            'transition': 'all 0.25s ease 0s'
                        });
                }
            },
            duration: 100,
        });
    });
```